# How would I refactor this Postgres query to get all purchases in a billing cycle?

Tags: sql, postgresql, refactoring

In this schema, each customer has a day of the month that they are billed on. That information is stored in `customer.billing_date` as an integer.

There is another table called `purchases`. Every day that a customer makes any purchases, a row is added to the `purchases` table with the date in `purchases.date`.

I want to know how much a customer purchased during their current billing period. The billing cycle is inclusive of their billing day. So if today is their billing day, then today's purchases will count toward the current billing period. However, if today is their billing day, then the query gets their total purchases for the last billing period.

I created this query to answer the question:

```
    SELECT
        p.customer_id,
        SUM(p.subtotal) AS total_period_purchases
    FROM
        purchases p
        JOIN customer c ON c.id = p.customer_id
    WHERE
        (
            -- Case 1: Their billing day hasn't passed in the current month, e.g. 9/26 was their last billing day and today is 10/19
            DATE_PART('DAY', now()) <= c.billing_date
            AND (
                (
                    -- Their purchase is from last month
                    DATE_PART('MONTH', p.date) = DATE_PART('MONTH', (now() - INTERVAL '1 month')) --
                    -- and on or after their billing day last month
                    AND DATE_PART('DAY', p.date) >= c.billing_date
                )
                OR (
                    -- Their purchase is from this month
                    DATE_PART('MONTH', p.date) = DATE_PART('MONTH', now()) -- and not on their billing day, if that happens to be today
                    AND DATE_PART('DAY', p.date) < c.billing_date
                )
            )
        )
        OR (
            -- Case 2: Their billing day has passed in the current month, e.g. 10/12 was their last billing day and today is 10/19
            DATE_PART('DAY', now()) > c.billing_date --
            -- Their purchase is from this month
            AND DATE_PART('MONTH', p.date) = DATE_PART('MONTH', now()) --
            -- and after their billing day this month
            AND DATE_PART('DAY', p.date) > c.billing_date
        )
    GROUP BY p.customer_id
```

Is there a way to refactor the `WHERE` clause of this query?

Comment: Please update your question to include sample data that covers all conditions, including row(s) which are not to be selected, and the complete table definitions (ddl). Provide this as formatted text - **no images**.  For a  good process creating [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Past the results between lines containing only ```; even better create a [fiddle](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Also include the expected results of that data, again as text.

Comment: I've long wondered if there a more elegant solution to this too